# AS3 - Returning a property of a class rather than the class itself

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

In ActionScript 3, there are some classes that will represent a value rather than the class itself. It's hard to explain properly what I mean, so take this example:

```
var str:String = "something";
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

trace(str); // something
trace(mc); // [object MovieClip]
```

You'll notice that the first trace outputs a value, rather than `[object String]`. Ontop of this, I can still make use of methods of `String`, like this:

```
var ar:Array = str.split('s');
```

Even though in a way you could almost read the above as:

```
"something".split('s');
```

I have a class `AvLevelData` that has some methods that deal with level data (which is essentially a String). At the moment there is a property `data:String` which represents the core level data.

The question I have is - can I replicate the behaviour of String in that when I trace or assign an instance of `AvLevelData`, the result is actually the String `data`.

For example, at the moment I need to go:

```
var levelData:AvLevelData = new AvLevelData();
trace(levelData.data);
```

To get the data. I instead want to be able to simply do the following:

```
var levelData:AvLevelData = new AvLevelData();
trace(levelData); // some level data string
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wan't your object to trace out your own fabricated string then you must implement a `toString()` function on your `AvLevelData` class.

In your example above, the `MovieClip` trace outputs: `[Object MovieClip]`; this comes from the default `toString()` implementation for `Object` (found on `Object.prototype`) . Note, you cannot override `toString()` as it only exists on the prototype of `Object` (remnants of the AS2/Javascript world), all you need to do is provide your own implementation with the same name. For instance:

```
public function toString():String {
   return "MyCustomObjectString";
}
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks for the concise explanation around why this doesn't need to be implemented using `override` - that would have caused me some headaches.

Comment: No problem! As an interesting aside: the `prototype` is still functional in AS3, for instance you could create a *custom* default `toString()` implementation for *all* `Object` instances. For example, try this: `Object.prototype = function():String { return "DefaultString" }`. Now when you trace your plain `MovieClip` (or any other `Object`) instance, it will return `DefaultString` instead. Note: it's generally highly unrecommended to provide alternative implementations to standard functions on the prototype; but it's a good educational example.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the most basic types - String, int, Number, uint, Boolean, to name a few - are not classes / objects per se, they are primitives. In some languages there is a wrapper class available for some of these so they can be treated like objects, though Flash doesn't do this so much from my experience.

Probably the best way to answer your question is to make a `toString()` method for your `AvLevelData` class:

```
public function toString():String {
    return data;
}
```

Any time you treat a class as a string (such as by putting it in `trace()`), flash (and many other languages) try to call toString() on the object. Typically this results in a string that's not helpful. But if you define your own `toString()` method, you can control what string gets output.

Another option is to simply do:

```
trace(AvLevelData.data);
```

Since that variable is a string, it should trace just fine.