# AS3 - Returning a property rather than the class itself

Tags: actionscript-3

As an extension to **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321857/as3-returning-a-property-of-a-class-rather-than-the-class-itself)**, where it was pointed out that I can use `toString()` to return any string desired when using `trace(instance)`, is it possible to return other types of objects?

For example, I may have this class:

```
public class List
{
    private var _content:Array = [];

    public function add():void{}
    public function remove():void{}
}
```

I normally need to make a getter that returns the `_content`, eg:

```
public function get content():Array{ return _content; }
```

So that I can do things like:

```
for each(var i:Object in myList.content)
```

Can I make `myList` in the above case actually return the value of `content` automatically? So that I can do like:

```
trace(myList); // item, item, item (similar output as tracing an array)
for each(var i:Object in myList)
```

Comment: How will virtual machine understand when it needs to return an object and when a property of that object?

Comment: @ValentinSimonov The same way that `toString()` works?

Comment: toString() is called when a STRING representation of an object is needed. What you are refering might be valueOf(). Check out the docs. But its use is limited and you will not be able to use it as you described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `toString` method, available in every class. `trace()` will always look for a `toString()` method otherwise it uses a default.

```
public function override toString():String
{
    return _content;
}
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Yeah, so I get this, but I don't want to return a String, I want to return anything such as an array, bitmap, sprite, number, etc.

Comment: `trace()` only outputs strings, tracing an `Array` object calls the object's `toString()` method which loops through each element and outputs the contents. To loop through the actual object as you appear to want in your original post, it would loop through the object's properties. You can't alter what's returned as that's already been hardcoded into the AVM. You'd have to alter the entire language structure to save a few characters of typing, and it would be much less readable/more complicated for others to understand whether you're looping through the object's properties or some custom thing.